# How to handle attributes of type "Set" in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, set, aura-attribute

I am trying to collect record Ids of changed records. Therefor I'm using `aura:attribute type="Set"`. But whenever I add the same id twice, it will be twice in my set. As described in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_collection.htm), there should be no duplicates. (Current Worakround is using `type="Map"`).

```
<aura:attribute name="mySet" type="Set" default="[]" access="private" />
```

Controller:

```
var recordId = "a0246000005mfR0AAI";
var mySet = cmp.get("v.mySet");

mySet.push(recordId);
mySet.push(recordId);
cmp.set("v.mySet", mySet);

var doublecheck = cmp.get("v.mySet");
```

Debug result:

> doublecheck = Proxy {0: "a0246000005mfR0AAI", 1: "a0246000005mfR0AAI",
>   length: 2}

**Am I handling the set wrong, or does it just not work yet?**

Comment: Have you tried using add instead of push?

Comment: @RahulSharma Yep, it told me `mySet.add is not a function`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that the problem is in javascript when you are declaring mySet.

Try this:

```
var mySet = new Set(component.get("v.mySet"));
```

Edit: the best solution is

```
var changes = cmp.get("v.changes") || new Set();
```

Comment: Worked, thanks! But if this is the solution, type="Set" seems to be useless, if I have to take care myself. Btw. I was able to do it like this: `var changes = cmp.get("v.changes") || new Set();` so the default [] seems not to do the right thing :/

Comment: `[]` is an array initializer, I wouldn't expect it to be equal to `new Set()`

Comment: It seems to be weird. I also believe type="Set" should have taken care of duplicates itself. Any thoughts?